# Quickly download selection of wallpapers

Tags: gratis, windows-7

I'm looking for a program (with GUI) for Windows 7, or a website (or a combination of both) that allows me to select multiple wallpapers, download them and display them periodically.

- Portable is not required
- I certainly don't want to be able to see individual pixels
- Downloading automatically and daily new wallpaper is a must

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### [John's Background Switcher (aka JBS)](http://johnsad.ventures/software/backgroundswitcher/)

- Is a program you install on your computer
  [image: JBS home screen]
- Works on Windows 98 to 8.1 (so also Windows 7) 32 and 64-bit

> Did I mention that JBS is completely free? Well it is! It will work happily on all 32 and 64-bit versions of Windows from Windows 98 up to Windows 8.1 (except Windows 7 Starter Edition). It uses Microsoft.NET 2.0 and if that’s not already installed on your computer the setup wizard will download and install it for you. If you have a version of JBS installed already just run the installer below and it’ll upgrade your settings for you – there’s no need to uninstall the current version first!

- Takes photos/images from either your computer (like images you have downloaded already) or various websites (with most of them you can set a category or tag). For some services you have to log in first (Facebook, Instagram, etc...)
  [image: Sources][image: Flickr dialog]
  *<sup>Flickr add dialog</sup>*
- You can set the minimum size in pixels in the settings
- It downloads the wallpapers automatically
- You can set the time interval yourself - so every day a new wallpaper is possible
- It has multi-monitor capabilities - handy if you have multiple monitors

Comment: aweosme recommendation

Comment: [Lifehacker article about JBS](http://lifehacker.com/5885032/the-best-wallpaper-manager-for-windows)