# Automatic Wallpaper Manager

Tags: windows, wallpaper

Are there programs that change, update, obtain via downloading or image websites Windows computers' desktop wallpapers (ie it'd superintend all the manual grind)?

For example, if I wanted picturesque wallpapers on Nordic scenery, I'd input this somewhere and this program would download/acquire the top-rated images of such and feature each for a duration (that I'd set) as my desktop wallpaper, before proceeding onto another.

This duplicates [the closed, but supernal inestimable, original at Superuser](https://superuser.com/q/679640/269574), which I replicate only for the benefit of those who can't view closed questions. [I've tried to ask the original answers there to post here](http://meta.superuser.com/q/8724/269574).

Comment: Seems to be a good answer at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4318/quickly-download-selection-of-wallpapers